# Using VS 2013, publishing a web site to Azure through the wizard, where would I find this website for later management within my MSDN Azure account?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I've recently built an ASP.NET website using C#. 
Using the publishing wizard within Visual Studio 2013 I see that I can publish to "Microsoft Azure Websites", and I have done so. It worked great.

However, logging into the Azure account I'm not able to locate this website anywhere so that I may manage it directly, and see what the burn rate (costs) are.

Where are these "Microsoft Azure Websites" stored once they are published, within Azure?

Many thanks in advance.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Web Apps in the old portal and under App Services in the new one.

Comment: Hi Lukos. Thank you. I looked at the old site, which I believe is manage.windowsazure.com, is that right? I found the Webapps link on the let, clicked and it does not show the site I just published, crazy eh? I then looked at the new site, and it also does NOT exist under App Services either. However, the site is live. #Confused

Comment: The only other possibility is that it was somehow published under another subscription rather than the one you are looking at in the portal?

Comment: Hi Lukos. Genius! I didn't even realize that was possible, given I only use my msdn account. Somehow it created a personal account and was burning down the free credit Microsoft gives you. Thanks for the great feedback, issue solved!